# Plotting with animation with matplotlib from file

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation

I am trying to plot a csv file made in this way (2 columns, obtained from a MD analysis) with pyplot.

```
FRAME,RMSD
0,0
1,1.404
2,1.816
3,1.728
4,1.385
5,2.071
6,2.139
7,0.929
8,1.457
9,1.249
10,1.203
11,1.212
```

I have no problem in plotting, but I cannot figure it out how to plot it with the animation of the line growing (with FuncAnimation of pyplot). Can anyone help me please?

I was wandering if I could use Pandas dataframe like this

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

dataframe = pd.read_csv('trajrmsd2.csv')
def get_data(table,rownum,title):
    data = pd.DataFrame(table.loc[rownum][2:]).astype(float)
    data.columns = {title}
    return data

title = 'RMSD'
d = get_data(dataframe,0,title)
x = np.array(d.index)
y = np.array(d['RMSD'])
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(y,x)
dataframe.columns = {title}

Writer = animation.writers['ffmpeg']
writer = Writer(fps=20, metadata=dict(artist='Me'), bitrate=1800)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
plt.xlim(0, 10000)
plt.ylim(0, 10) 
plt.xlabel('Frame',fontsize=20)
plt.ylabel(title,fontsize=20)
plt.title('RMSD',fontsize=20)

def animate(i):
    data = dataframe.iloc[:int(i+1)] 
    p = sns.lineplot(x=data.index, y=data[title], data=data, color="r")
    p.tick_params(labelsize=17)
    plt.setp(p.lines,linewidth=7)

ani = matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, 
init_func=get_data, frames=17, repeat=True)

ani.save('RMSD.mp4', writer=writer)
```

And this is the error that I get...

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "animatooooooo.py", line 44, in 
ani.save('RMSD.mp4', writer=writer)
File "/home/dbassani/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 1128, in save
anim._init_draw()  # Clear the initial frame
File "/home/dbassani/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 1706, in _init_draw
self._drawn_artists = self._init_func()
TypeError: get_data() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'table', 'rownum', and 'title'
Exception ignored in: <function TimerQT.**del** at 0x7f33ecbff0d0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/dbassani/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt5.py", line 189, in **del**
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Comment: Can you provide the code you've tried and specify what didn't work for you?

Comment: I have provided it, I hope it is reasonable. If You have suggestions I would be very happy! Thanks